# AngularJS with angular-ui bootstrap - getting it IE8 compatible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get some AngularJS code that uses [angular-ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to work in IE 8. I am using the guidance in the [AngularJS developer guide on IE](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie). I added the following code to my **index.html** page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.createElement('alert');
        document.createElement('ng-include');
        document.createElement('bookviewer');
        document.createElement('accordion');
        document.createElement('accordion-group');
        document.createElement('accordion-heading');
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    :
```

Problem is: I can't get it to work... The above lines are part of a complete code set that is too large to include here. I added the complete code to a github respository at https://github.com/svdoever/AngularJS-bookviewer.
Is there something I forget, or is AngularJS+angular-ui bootstrap+IE8 a combination that will never work?

I deployed a version of my example to http://svdoever-playground.azurewebsites.net/.

Comment: I spotted a typo in `id` attribute. You forgot the opening quote.

Comment: @leesei: thx, added the missing quote, didn't solve the issue:-)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding augment.js.
https://github.com/javascript/augment
The issue was that bootstrap.js is using JS function that IE8 does not implement.
Augment.js just fill the gap.